# Не работает bootstrap markdown

Tags: html, bootstrap, markdown

Сделано все по инструкции, самое меню показывает которое прописано тут

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="text" data-provide="markdown-editable" data-provide="markdown" name="text" rows="3" placeholder="Введите текст сообщения"></textarea>
```

А вот текст который выводится не форматирует под ббкоды

```
 <div data-provide="markdown-editable">
    <?php echo nl2br($item['message']) ?>
 </div>
```

Как решить проблему ?